# to get the value of selected month and print the dates

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $month=array("January"=>"01","February"=>"02","March"=>"03","April"=>"04","May"=>"05","June"=>"06","July"=>"07","August"=>"08","September"=>"09",
    "October"=>"10","November"=>"11","December"=>"12");

    echo"<select name='month'>";
    echo"<option>-select-</option>";
    foreach($month as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$key."</option>"."<br />";
    }

    echo"</select>";

    $input_month=$month;    
    $mkt = mktime(0,0,0,$input_month,1,date("Y"))   ;
    $date2 = date("Y-m-d",$mkt);    
    $end2= date("Y")."-".$input_month."-".date('t', strtotime($date2));
?>
<table>
   <tr>
   <?php while(strtotime($date2) <= strtotime($end2)) {
        $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date2));
        $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date2));
        $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date2)));

        echo "<td>$day_num <br/> $day_name</td>";
   }
  ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here i want that if for example i select the month 'May' then its value '05' i should get it and assign it to $input_month so that dates of  selected month with day name should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>

        <?php
        $month = array("January" => "1",
            "February" => "2",
            "March" => "3",
            "April" => "4",
            "May" => "5",
            "June" => "6",
            "July" => "7",
            "August" => "8",
            "September" => "9",
            "October" => "10",
            "November" => "11",
            "December" => "12");
        ?>
        <form>
            <select name="month">
                <?php foreach ($month as $key => $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
                        <?php echo $key; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['month'])) {
            $inputMonth = $_GET['month'];
            $mkt = mktime(0, 0, 0, $inputMonth, 1, date("Y"));
            $date2 = date("Y-m-d", $mkt);
            $end2 = date("Y") . "-" . $inputMonth . "-" . date('t', strtotime($date2));
            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    while (strtotime($date2) <= strtotime($end2)) {
                        $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date2));
                        $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date2));
                        $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date2)));

                        echo "<td>$day_num <br/> $day_name</td>";
                    }// end while 
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php } //end if 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should i pass at $input_month=?  $month or $value"

Comment: it is giving error                                                                                                   Warning: mktime() expects parameter 4 to be long, array given in E:\xampp\htdocs\gg_hrms\date-final.php on line 29

Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\gg_hrms\date-final.php on line 32

Comment: Well, I just corrected code, okay wait I will give you full code.

Comment: thanks for your help                                                                                        But i ran this code it is not showing the output i.e the calendar is not displaying

Comment: You will see code like drop down menu of months, Select any month and submit it. You will surely get answer.

Comment: thank you for your help. The code is working fine                                                but it is not holding the month i select, after i select the month and click on submit button it shows January in drop down list.If you can please resolve this it would be very helpful.                                                                                   
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the select item use:

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
```

You question makes it uncertain for me if this is all within the same file or not. If this doesn't solve your problem, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: all the code is in same file.  i have successfully got the value in the drop down list. My question is that if i select a month than its value i want it and assign it to $input_month variable so that it can calculate the number of days of selected month.                                                                                                                                       If you can suggest me any other easy method it would be helpful to do that task what i am trying.                                                                                    Thank You